# how to remove icon fa-plus with fa-minus for first div with class "boshkeDetails" when page was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some div with class "boshkeDetails" that they have div with class "detailsBoshkeColapse" inside it and first div of "boshkeDetails" is opened .I want to remove icon fa-plus for first div with class "boshkeDetails" and relace it with fa-minus when the page was loaded.but my code do not work correctly.how I can solve it ? 
I put my code in below link:
https://codepen.io/elhambgh4/pen/QZyedY

```
           <div class="boshkeDetails">
    <div class="DetailsCategory" data-toggle="collapse" href="#boshkeDetails-1">
        <div class="text">
            <h4>item1.Name</h4>
            <div class="iconPlus iconPlusGray">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" id="icon"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailsBoshkeColapse collapse in" id="boshkeDetails-1">
        <div class="content-boshkeDetails">
            <p>
               item1.Content
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="boshkeDetails">
    <div class="DetailsCategory" data-toggle="collapse" href="#boshkeDetails-2">
        <div class="text">
            <h4>item2.Name</h4>
            <div class="iconPlus iconPlusGray">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" id="icon"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailsBoshkeColapse collapse" id="boshkeDetails-2">
        <div class="content-boshkeDetails">
            <p>
               item2.Content
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
if ($(".detailsBoshkeColapse").hasClass('in')) {
    var icon = $(this)
    icon.prev(".DetailsCategory").find('.iconPlus i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');   
}

$('.DetailsCategory').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().hasClass('in')) {

        $(this).find('.text .iconPlus i').toggleClass('fa-plus').toggleClass('fa-minus');
        $(this).find('.text .iconPlus').toggleClass('iconPlusRed').toggleClass('iconPlusGray');

    } else {
        $(this).find('.text .iconPlus i').toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus');
        $(this).find('.text .iconPlus').toggleClass('iconPlusGray').toggleClass('iconPlusRed');
    }
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

`var icon = $(this)`

to

`var icon = $('.detailsBoshkeColapse.in')`

Thats all your code works fine
 **Note:** you are using this outside of an event(click, change, hover, focus etc) and so in your code jQuery(this) refers to window object when used outside of an event

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
const onload = () => {
  const icon = document.querySelector(".boshkeDetails .fa-plus");

  if (icon) {
    icon.classList.remove("fa-plus");
    icon.classList.add("fa-minus");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", onload)
```

It is trying to find the first element with selector `".boshkeDetails .fa-plus"` and toggles it's class.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but not quite there. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.DetailsCategory').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().hasClass('in')) {
            $(this).find('.text .iconPlus i').toggleClass('fa-plus').toggleClass('fa-minus');
            $(this).find('.text .iconPlus').toggleClass('iconPlusRed').toggleClass('iconPlusGray');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.text .iconPlus i').toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus');
            $(this).find('.text .iconPlus').toggleClass('iconPlusGray').toggleClass('iconPlusRed');
        }
    });

    $(".detailsBoshkeColapse.in").prev('.DetailsCategory').trigger('click');  
});
```

The line

```
$(".detailsBoshkeColapse.in").prev('.DetailsCategory').trigger('click');
```

finds the element and triggers the click. If you have multiple elements with the 'in' class then use the [jquery .first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) filter.